# When filling in a Schengen airport transit visa application, where should the reference number of the final destination country visa be recorded?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, germany, transit-visas, applications

When applying for a Schengen airport transit visa, Q29 of the [visa application form](https://havanna.diplo.de/blob/2305938/22a9e62f4ccbc6543c38362d386a577a/planilla-visa-schengen--nueva--data.pdf) from the website of the German Embassy in Havana asks for the following details about the applicant’s entry permit for the final destination country:

- issued by
- valid from / to dates

It doesn’t have a specific place to record the entry permit (visa) number.

By contrast, Q20 (which relates to *residency* in a country other than the applicant’s country of citizenship) *does* ask for the permit number.

Question: Which is the correct place in the form for an applicant who holds a long term multiple entry *visitor* visa to record the number of that visa?

Note: I’m asking what might seem a trivial/obvious question because its a first time application and I want to avoid the possibility of the application being deemed invalid and rejected.

Comment: NAA, but all Schengen visas ever are recorded in the VIS, thus the number is not useful as what you stated in that can be easily cross-checked. A foreign PR number can't be cross-checked like that

Comment: I think residency is about to check if it is true residency (or just some short term permit), to restrict visa shopping. (local embassy may know about codes (format, types, and possibly number range for a specific date).

Comment: Q29 does **not** ask about the Visa number of your final destination, only who issued it and valid from/to.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes, I know that, I’m asking if the final destination visa number should be recorded anywhere. A friend recently applied for a [transit visa from the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182762/what-to-do-when-schengen-transit-without-visa-rules-change-mid-trip), VFS insisted the UK visa number/details had to be recorded at Q20  (in fact, they amended the application my friend had completed and charged for the ‘admin’). It made no sense to my friend at the time, and seems wrong given Q20 relates to *residence*.

Comment: Sounds to me more like a rip off from VFS.